# How to change Power BI Date/Time format from Day, Month dd, yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a column in Power BI and i have changed it's type to Date/Time , the data in Power Query Editor looks like below

[image]

I want to use this column as x-axis to plot a line chart and in Power BI report the data looks like below

[image]

However, I want the data to appear in the below format on Report as well

[image]

Can anyone help me with what is missing here ? I want the chart to just display date and month like
[image]

but in my case it is coming like this
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column you are referring as a date here probably a Date Hierarchy field and as a reason reports showing dates in that format (default). Anyway, you can change the format from the **Format** tab in the ribbon and set you expected date format from the list. Available formats are shown below-

[image]

Alternatively, you can simply create a new **Measure** or **Custom Column** from your **Date** column and use them in the report.

**Measure**

```
measure_date_format = MIN(your_table_name[your_date_column_name])
```

**Custom Column**

```
column_date_format = your_table_name[your_date_column_name]
```